# TranslateZ adding extra white space at the bottom of html container element

Tags: html, css, parallax

I am trying to create a parallax effect in which different elements scroll at different speeds by applying 3-d transform

**Problem**

I have a container with a class of `parallax`. Whenever i add a div inside it which contains multiple layers translated at Z coordinate, there's extra white space added at the bottom of container with the class of `parallax`

How can i remove this extra white space?

Code

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.parallax {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  perspective: 10px;
}

.parallax__group {
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: transform 0.7s ease;
}

.parallax__layer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.title {
  font-size: 1.7rem;
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.parallax__layer--back {  
  transform: translateZ(-5px) scale(1.5);
  z-index: 3;
}

.parallax__layer--base {
  transform: translateZ(0);
  z-index: 4;
}

.parallax__group:nth-of-type(1) {
  z-index: 2;
}

#group1 .parallax__layer {
  background: #36ffbf;
}

#group2 .parallax__layer--back {
  background: #00f1a4;
}
```

```html
<div class="parallax">
    <div id="group1" class="parallax__group">
      <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--base">
        <div class="title">Base Layer</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="group2" class="parallax__group">
      <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--back">
        <div class="title">Background Layer</div>
      </div>
      <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--base">
        <div class="title">Base Layer</div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `overflow: hidden;` to `.parallax__group` and your whitespace goes.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.parallax {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  perspective: 10px;
}

.parallax__group {
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: transform 0.7s ease;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.parallax__layer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.title {
  font-size: 1.7rem;
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.parallax__layer--back {  
  transform: translateZ(-5px) scale(1.5);
  z-index: 3;
}

.parallax__layer--base {
  transform: translateZ(0);
  z-index: 4;
}

.parallax__group:nth-of-type(1) {
  z-index: 2;
}

#group1 .parallax__layer {
  background: #36ffbf;
}

#group2 .parallax__layer--back {
  background: #00f1a4;
}
```

```html
<div class="parallax">
    <div id="group1" class="parallax__group">
      <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--base">
        <div class="title">Base Layer</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="group2" class="parallax__group">
      <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--back">
        <div class="title">Background Layer</div>
      </div>
      <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--base">
        <div class="title">Base Layer</div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: removing translateZ affects the parallax effect. translateZ is added to different layers to make them scroll at different speeds

Comment: I am sorry, i misspelled `overflow` property. Problem fixed. Thanyou!

Comment: Glad to help :)

Comment: just a little followup on my question. I am trying to emulate the scrolling behavior as shown [on this website](https://rededition.com/en/). If you scroll up or down, you will notice how content on this page animates like there's elasticity between them. Do you know if there's any library that allows these kind of animations?

Comment: Site can't be reached.. But I'm sure you can find how they do that kind of animations if you deep dive site's codes.

Answer (score -1):

I removed the `perspective` attribute and added some padding.
Hope this helps!

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.parallax {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.parallax__group {
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: transform 0.7s ease;
}

.parallax__layer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.title {
  font-size: 1.7rem;
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.parallax__layer--back {  
  transform: translateZ(-5px) scale(1.5);
  z-index: 3;
  padding-top: 50px;
}

.parallax__layer--base {
  transform: translateZ(0px);
  z-index: 4;
}

.parallax__group:nth-of-type(1) {
  z-index: 2;
}

#group1 .parallax__layer {
  background: #36ffbf;
}

#group2 .parallax__layer--back {
  background: #00f1a4;
}
```

```html
<div class="parallax">
    <div id="group1" class="parallax__group">
      <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--base">
        <div class="title">Base Layer</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="group2" class="parallax__group">
      <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--back">
        <div class="title">Background Layer</div>
      </div>
      <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--base">
        <div class="title">Base Layer</div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```